# IOS: UITableView have to double click to deselect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView that holds a tableView that populates 'prototype cells' from a mutable array and whose cells show an 'accessory checkmark' when you select them. I have a textfield in a view below the tableview and whose data I am then appending to the array that is populating the tableview. My problem is that after I append the new data which adds a cell to the tableview I have to touch a cell twice in order to deselect any of the cells I previously selected.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"skillName" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = skillsOptions[indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [skillsList removeObject:skillsOptions[indexPath.row]];
}

-(void)grabSelectedSkills {

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
        NSString *skill = skillsOptions[indexPath.row];
        //NSString *skill = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)indexPath.row];
        [skillsList addObject:skill];
    }
    NSLog(@"skillsList: %@",skillsList);
}
- (IBAction)continue:(id)sender {
    [self grabSelectedSkills];
}
- (IBAction)addOtherSkills:(id)sender {
    if (self.otherSkill.text.length > 1) {
    [skillsOptions addObject:self.otherSkill.text];


    self.otherSkill.text = @"";
    [self.tableView endEditing:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: You need to track your selection/deselection status outside of the cell - a dictionary keyed by the "skill option" is probably a good choice. You can then use this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to add/remove the check mark as required. You should deselect the row in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and get rid of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track your selection/deselection status outside of the cell - a dictionary keyed by the "skill option" is probably a good choice.

You can then use this in cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath to add/remove the check mark as required. You should deselect the row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and get rid of didDeselectRowAtIndexPath -

Create `self.selectedCells` as an `NSMutableDictionary` property.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"skillName" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSString *skillOption=skillsOptions[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = skillOption;

    if (self.selectedCells[skillOption]!= nil) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *skillOption=skillsOptions[indexPath.row];

    if (self.selectedCells[skillOption]!= nil) {
        tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.selectedCells removeObjectForKey:skillOption];
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self.selectedCells[skillOption]=skillOption;
    }
    [tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only use didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method (drop the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: method) and check to select the cell if it's not and vice versa as-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   BOOL cellSelected = NO;
   // set cellSelected based on your condition
   if(cellSelected)
   {
      // code to deselect the cell
   }
   else
   {
      // code to select the cell
      UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     //tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO;
     tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   }
}
```

Comment: What does the cellSelected do? I don't see how it get's called. Do I have to tie it to something?

Comment: cellSelected is just a BOOL variable holding the status whether a cell is selected or not, every time you touch on a cell either selected/ unselected didSelecteRowAtIndexPath: will be called

Comment: you need not to tie any thing, just the remove the deselectRowAtIndexPath: and do deselection stuff inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath: based the cellSelected BOOL status